# Transform to adjacent matrix(from-to) from a long format data

Tags: r, dplyr

This looks almost like `pivot_wide` operation except that there's a need to 'duplicate' the entries to ensure we capture the complete from-to process.

I suspect this could be a frequent routine in network analysis, but not sure whether there's a function readily available to get such transformation.

Thank you

```
ID <- c(rep('A',2), rep('B',3))
process <- c('Category_8', 'Category_1', 'Category_3', 'Category_4', 'Category_1')

have <- tibble(
  ID,
  process
)
have
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  ID    process   
  <chr> <chr>     
1 A     Category_8
2 A     Category_1
3 B     Category_3
4 B     Category_4
5 B     Category_1
```

```
ID <- c(rep('A',1), rep('B',2))
From <- c('Category_8', 'Category_3', 'Category_4')
To <- c('Category_1', 'Category_4', 'Category_1')

want <- tibble(
  ID,
  From,
  To
)
want
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ID    From       To        
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
1 A     Category_8 Category_1
2 B     Category_3 Category_4
3 B     Category_4 Category_1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lead` to get next value of `process` for each `ID` and drop rows with `NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)

have %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  transmute(ID, from = process, to = lead(process)) %>%
  na.omit()

#  ID    from       to        
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>     
#1 A     Category_8 Category_1
#2 B     Category_3 Category_4
#3 B     Category_4 Category_1
```